# How to install VMware Tools on VMware Workstation 7.1.6 on host machine

Tags: linux, windows-7, vmware, vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

I am attempting to install VMware Tools on VMware Workstation 7.1.6 on my Linux Redhat host machine. I have searched for a source to download but have been unsuccessful. Can anyone provide a link to where I can download VMware Tools for Linux Redhat OS?

I am trying to install VMware Tools so I can run a repair on a Windows 7 VM that has a corrupted Windows Boot File causing an error to be displayed when I attempt to power on the machine.

I am running VMware Workstation 7.1.6 x64 and the file I am attempting to repair with built in utility command on VMware Tools is Windows 7 x64. Please let me know if anyone has experienced a similar issue and if the VMware Tools utility command works to repair/restore corrupted or missing Windows Boot files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vmware tools came up with workstation only, you can right click on VM menu, you can install,

Generally it will not automatically install the tools, it will mount an iso like cd rom to the vm,

you need to mount it and extract the tar file, then run the vmware-tools-install.pl file